# CentOS - Trying to downgrade php

Tags: php, centos, yum, downgrade

I need to downgrade PHP 5.3 to 5.2 and I'm on a CentOS 5.5 x86_64 machine running Apache 2.2.3 & MySQL 5.1.54. I've been having some problems and now am just plain lost...  Not sure exactly what to include in terms of steps / whatnot, so I'll just try to break down what I did that got me to my breaking point...

Here are the steps I've taken thus far:

(1) I tried uninstalling PHP 5.3 with:

```
rpm -e --nodeps php-devel php php-cli php-common php-mcrypt php-mysql 
php-pdo php-ldap php-mbstring php-xml php-xmlrpc php-odbc php-imap 
php-snmp php-gd

//Yielded:
warning: /etc/php.ini saved as /etc/php.ini.rpmsave
```

(2) Then, I tried installing php:

```
yum install php-devel php php-cli php-common php-mcrypt php-mysql php-pdo php-ldap php-mbstring php-xml php-xmlrpc php-odbc php-imap php-snmp php-gd
```

But, stupidly, I realized (later on) that I didn't specify the repo or the php version.  Fortunately (?), nothing was installed because it yielded this:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  package libmcrypt-2.5.8-4.el5.centos.x86_64 (which is newer than libmcrypt-2.5.7-5.el5.i386) is already installed
```

(3) Although, I didn't notice that at first, so I restarted apache, and ran:
yum upgrade

Which ran through everything fine.

(4) Edited /etc/my.cnf to put skip-bdb in there and start mysqld

(5) Ran: `mysql_upgrade -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`

(6) After trying to google for a solution, I came across an article that said I needed yum-allowdowngrade, so, I ran this: `yum install yum-allowdowngrade`

(7) To try to make sure I didn't have php installed, I ran: yum remove php

which yielded:

```
Loaded plugins: allowdowngrade, fastestmirror
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: php
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www6.atomicorp.com
 * base: mirror.rackspace.com
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
 * updates: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
atomic                                                                                        | 1.9 kB     00:00     
base                                                                                          | 2.1 kB     00:00     
epel                                                                                          | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                        | 2.1 kB     00:00     
rusia-repo                                                                                    |  951 B     00:00     
updates                                                                                       | 1.9 kB     00:00     
Package(s) php available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

(8) Then, I ran:

```
yum --allow-downgrade --enablerepo=rusia-repo install php-devel-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 php-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 php-cli-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 php-common-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 php-mcrypt-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 php-mysql-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 php-pdo-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 php-ldap-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 php-mbstring-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 php-xml-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 php-xmlrpc-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 php-odbc-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 php-imap-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 php-snmp-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 php-gd-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64
```

which yielded:

```
Loaded plugins: allowdowngrade, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www6.atomicorp.com
 * base: mirror.rackspace.com
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
 * updates: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
atomic                                                                                        | 1.9 kB     00:00     
base                                                                                          | 2.1 kB     00:00     
epel                                                                                          | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                        | 2.1 kB     00:00     
rusia-repo                                                                                    |  951 B     00:00     
updates                                                                                       | 1.9 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.2.17-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.17-1.el5 for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli = 5.2.17-1.el5 for package: php
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 from rusia-repo has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.17-1.el5 is needed by package php-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 (rusia-repo)
php-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 from rusia-repo has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-cli = 5.2.17-1.el5 is needed by package php-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 (rusia-repo)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.17-1.el5 is needed by package php-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 (rusia-repo)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-cli = 5.2.17-1.el5 is needed by package php-5.2.17-1.el5.x86_64 (rusia-repo)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I kept getting a series of these errors, so decided to just run yum update, update back to php 5.3 and see if I could get that working until I figured out how to downgrade correctly...

So, I ran yum update and got:

```
yum update
Loaded plugins: allowdowngrade, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www6.atomicorp.com
 * base: mirror.rackspace.com
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: mirror.symnds.com
 * updates: mirror.symnds.com
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

Then, I ran:

```
yum install php-devel php php-cli php-common php-mcrypt php-mysql php-pdo php-ldap php-mbstring php-xml php-xmlrpc php-odbc php-imap php-snmp php-gd
```

But that yielded:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  package libmcrypt-2.5.8-4.el5.centos.x86_64 (which is newer than libmcrypt-2.5.7-5.el5.i386) is already installed
  file /usr/bin/phar.phar from install of php-cli-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package php-cli-5.3.6-3.el5.art.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/phpize from install of php-cli-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package php-cli-5.3.6-3.el5.art.x86_64
```

I tried service httpd restart and got:

```
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So, now, I'm totally confused and really, really need some help...

Comment: I guess the question was migrated from StackOverflow, although, I'm super happy to know this site exists as well... So thanks, migrator... Just wanted to accept / thanks both GruffTech & quanta for their help. I did wind up doing as GruffTech suggested and uninstalled everything, then downloaded and installed the RPMs. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

everytime something like this happened to me (needing an older copy then what is in repo, or newer) I've found it easier to build my own RPM's from source, and i recommend doing that.

Its not too difficult, just a little more time consuming, and you can ensure your using the latest of everything ELSE on your system, and just the older (or newer) versions of PHP.

http://www.imminentweb.com/technologies/create-centos-php-rpm

should help you with the basics of building your own PHP RPM's on CentOS.

If you continue down the path your headed, your probably going to run into what I call "dependency hell"  Old PHP needs old version of X, which is needed by a new version of Y, and if you want the old version of X, you need to downgrade Y as well, so on and so forth.   10-15 dependencies later, your running a reasonably insecure environment because a significant chunk of your system is running old code.

Comment: Links appears to be broken. Page never loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The "Missing Dependency" error is often caused by mixing repositories. I suggest you disabled the `atomic`, `epel` repos and try again with [CentOS testing](http://dev.centos.org/centos/5/testing/x86_64/RPMS/) repo based on [this](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/PHP_5.1_To_5.2) guide or [Jason Litka](http://www.jasonlitka.com/yum-repository/) repo.

Answer (score 0):

YOu may want to try:
yum downgrade php

Before you do so disable any add-on repos.  A major problem you will face is that some add-on repos may install dependencies required for PHP 5.3 but not needed for PHP 5.2 (such as varying sqlite versions).

In this case, you may have to force remove the modules:

rpm -e --nodeps pkgname

Then try the downgrade.

If all else fails, remove all php 5.3 packages with rpm -e --nodeps and then just re-install using the centOS sources.